# WPF: DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate: Only show details if single row is selected?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, rowdetailstemplate

I'm using the `RowDetailsTemplate` in one of my `DataGrids`. This works fine so far, but looks really odd when the user wants to select multiple rows for specific operations.
Is there a simple way to display the `RowDetailsTemplate` only if exactly only one row is selected?

I'd love to solve this with pure XAML. Otherwise I'd do it with code behind:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid temp = sender as DataGrid;

    if (temp.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
    {
        temp.RowDetailsVisibilityMode = DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.VisibleWhenSelected;
    }
    else
    {
        temp.RowDetailsVisibilityMode = DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGrid has a property *RowDetailsVisibilityMode*. Set it to *Collapsed* when more than one row is selected.
Your XAML should look something like

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="{Binding Path=SelectedItems.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource rdtvc}}">
```

and the corresponding converter like

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        if (value != null && (int)value == 1)
            return DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.VisibleWhenSelected;
        else 
            return DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and what would be the best way to do that? I'd love to do that in XAML, but I cannot think of a proper way to do that...

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer by user1994514 I developed a XAML-only version without the need for a converter. In case someone wants to avoid the additional converter you can use a style with a data trigger to achieve the same effect.

```
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Style>
    </DataGrid>
```